# jQuery blueimp fileupload firefox/opera calculations issue, chrome is ok

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am using jQuery blueimp fileupload and having different output in firefox/opera in functions `progress` and `progressall`. Chrome works fine, the output in console.log() is

```
100
100
```

while output in FF/Opera is:

```
100
95
```

Outputs correct values:

```
progress: function(e, data) {
  var value;
  value = Math.round((data.loaded / data.total) * 100) || 0;

  console.log(value);
},
```

Outputs strange values:

```
progressall: function(e, data) {
  var value;
  value = Math.round((data.loaded / data.total) * 100) || 0;

  console.log(value);
},
```

Btw. this is tested on 1 file and it should give same output. The problem also occurs on multiple files it just shows strange overall percentage.....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery file upload progress bar inaccurate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593392/jquery-file-upload-progress-bar-inaccurate)

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my problem (it doesn't) make sense at all, but it works... duhh changing this:

```
loaded = parseInt(
      e.loaded / e.total * (data.chunkSize || total),
      10
) + (data.uploadedBytes || 0);
```

to

```
loaded = parseInt(
       e.loaded / e.loaded * (data.chunkSize || total),
       10
) + (data.uploadedBytes || 0);
```

Comment: Yes, this solution does not make sense but it works. Any idea why? Did you find any other reasonable solution?

Comment: i noticed that with this "solution" the progress bar moves to 100% faster than a file is uploaded... Try to upload big file, the progress will move very fast, while the file is still uploading. You can that with console.log. So this is just a cosmetic "workaround"

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, found the cause.

Here is the content of `jquery_file_upload\server\php\index.php:`

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
```

With this server side upload script -> no problems with the progress bar, it's reaching 100%.

The problem appears with the following code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
$var="111";
print_r($var);
```

print_r($var) or any echo is causing the progress bar problem...

So the solution would be: no "echo".

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
return;
```

Does that work for anybody else?