# jquery file upload progress bar inaccurate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I am using jquery file upload (http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) plugin.

My Code:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: 'server/index.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    dropZone: $('#dropzone'),
}).bind('fileuploadprogress', function (e, data) {
    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
    $('.progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
});
```

When I do the file upload, the progress bar is very inaccurate. Every time when I upload no matter what size the file is, the progress bar will always stuck at around 10% until the file is upload finish, then it will directly goes up to 100%.

Why is it behave like that? How can I fix it to properly display the progress?

Thank you.

Comment: How big are the files you are testing with, and have you tested it remote and not locally where the files will be uploaded instantaneously, due to bandwidth == disk access bandwidth.

Comment: @thetrompf Yeah, at first I was testing on locally. Which it feels like everything is perfectly working. But, when I tried with hosting server, then I face the problem as described in my question.

Comment: which browser and web server are you using?

Comment: @thetrompf Firefox and Dreamhost. Tested with IE 11 as well, also inaccurate. The progress bar straight away goes from 0% to 100% when the file just started to upload.

Comment: What is the size of the file you are testing with? The progress callback is called based on a time interval, and if it isn't called often enough on small files it will seem it goes from 0 to 100 instantly, or maybe you're just using too small files for you bandwidth. So the file will be uploaded before the first fileprogress callback is called.

Comment: @thetrompf Actually I am using quite a large file which it took about 20 seconds to complete the upload.

Comment: I just double check with their original example. It seems like it is the "default" problem by itself.

Comment: @user1995781 Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @AwladLiton Yes. That is by not using progress bar....

Comment: @user1995781 is there any other way?

Comment: @AwladLiton If you know other way, please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the file progress bar issue too. The odd thing is that the same implementation works on another site I have developed, but not on another. Odd as it may be, I struggled for hours trying to find out what is going on. I read another problem somewhere and blueimp here says it tested fine using similar setups, and someone mentioned that they had a proxy. Well I don't have a proxy, but then I checked it on another computer. Works fine, yet another computer, works fine again. Then I disabled AVG on my main computer, and wouldn't you know, works fine. Seems that with AVG enabled my data.loaded would almost always be the same as data.total. I'm sure it has to do with some stupid cache or something that they implement to "boost" your browsing speed.

Comment: Good find, it saved me allot of debugging.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you use the default `autoUpload` option the files are submitted immediately in the `add` callback and for the first `n` calls to `progressall` callback, the `data.total` is not fully updated. (`n` depends on workstation speed and on `progressInterval` option)

The solution I have found is to calculate the total files length in the 1st call of `add` and to use it in the `progressall`.

```
var originalAdd = $.blueimp.fileupload.prototype.options.add;
var iFilesCount = 0;
var dataTotal = 0;

$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    ...
    progressall: function (e, data) {
        if (dataTotal == 0) {
            dataTotal = 1;
        }
        var iProgress = parseInt(data.loaded / dataTotal * 100, 10);
        $('#progress .progress-bar').css('width', iProgress + '%');
    },
    add: function (e, data) {
        if (iFilesCount <= 0) {
            iFilesCount = data.originalFiles.length;
            dataTotal = 0;
            var i = 0;
            // sum up files lengths
            for (i=0; i < iFilesCount ;i++){
                dataTotal = dataTotal + data.originalFiles[i].size;
            }
        }
        iFilesCount--;
        // recall default add callback
        originalAdd.call(this, e, data);
    }
    ...
}
```

The output of console.log( data.loaded + ' / ' + data.total + ' / ' + dataTotal) in `progressall`

```
  536710 /  1610128 / 30060524 \
 1073418 /  6977218 / 30060524 |
 1610128 /  8587402 / 30060524 |
 2146838 / 12881204 / 30060524 |
 2683550 / 13954660 / 30060524 |
 3220258 / 16638300 / 30060524 |-- progress bar is not accurate
 3756968 / 19858646 / 30060524 |
 4293676 / 24689178 / 30060524 |
 4830384 / 27909544 / 30060524 /
 5367092 / 30060524 / 30060524 \
 5903800 / 30060524 / 30060524 |
 6440510 / 30060524 / 30060524 |
 6977218 / 30060524 / 30060524 |
 7513946 / 30060524 / 30060524 |
 8050674 / 30060524 / 30060524 |-- accurate progress bar
 ...                           |
 ...                           |
30060524 / 30060524 / 30060524 /
```