# jQuery File Upload progessall not using combined file totals

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

When uploading multiple image files, the first several have the same 'progressall' values as 'progress' does so my progress bar goes to 100% immediately. Then later it goes back to 0% and goes up as expected to 100%.  Perhaps I'm not setting options correctly?

I'm loading: fileupload.js, fileupload-process.js, and fileupload-image.js

Initializing as:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    sequentialUploads: false,
    progressall: function (e, data) {
        console.log('progressAll', data.loaded, data.total);
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('progress').attr({value: data.loaded, max: data.total});
        $("#progress-amt").text(progress + '%');
    },
    progress: function (e, data) {
        console.log('progress', data.loaded, data.total);
    }
});
```

In my test uploading around 18 images at one time, the first 15 files have the same numbers for 'progress' and 'progressall' like:
    progress 409631 409631  // loaded, total
    progressAll 409631 409631 // loaded, total

Then it starts to look like I would expect:
progress 2794725 2794725
progressAll 2794725 5663799
progress 2869074 2869074
progressAll 5663799 8484180
progress 2820381 2820381
progressAll 8484180 8484180

Even then the total increments at first.  I would expect the 'total' in 'progressall' to be the combined total bytes of all the files that were selected from the very first call to 'progressall'.

Am I misunderstanding or misconfiguring something?

Comment: Nobody?  Is this a dead library or should I be posting somewhere else?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Hehe, that was a long time ago.  I don't recall but I don't think I got it working.  May have switched to a different tool as there was no feedback.  Sorry...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery file upload progress bar inaccurate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593392/jquery-file-upload-progress-bar-inaccurate)