# Blueimp JQuery File Upload Progressall not working properly

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I try to use the Blueimp File Uploader in the following case:

- User clicks a button, an input file field is triggered and the user can select one or multiple files to upload.
- After selecting the files, the files are uploaded automatically because of the autoupload setting. One progessbar appears to show to progress of all upload together.
- After all files are uploaded, there appears a modal with a list of all files and the status (`uploaded` or `upload failed`).

There is an event called `progressall`. With the vars `data.loaded` and `data.total` you should be able to determine the progress in %. But the first few calls of `progressall` don't have the right value for `data.total`, so the progressbar is behaving weird, it's going up and down in the beginning before working properly.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a known issue of the library?

Comment: I have the same problem, I think that while still counting `data.total`, the upload is already started and `progressall` callback is already fired.. I'm still searching for a solution.

Comment: I ended up counting the total size manually, it feels a little bit hacky, but works fine

Comment: I did the same, I used `add` callback to sum up files lengths in a global var

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery file upload progress bar inaccurate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593392/jquery-file-upload-progress-bar-inaccurate)